Characterisation on growth bound, A short course on operator semigroups Chapter V, Exercise 3.10, (1)
I am trying to prove the Exercise 3.10 (1) in Chapter V of "A short course on operator semigroups" by Engel and Nagel. The claim is:
Let $(A,D(A))$ be the generator of a strongly continuous semigroup on a complex Hilbert space $H$. Then holds
\begin{align*}
    \omega_0(A) = \inf\left\{ \omega > s(A) \,\, : \,\, \sup_{r \in \mathbb{R}} ||R(\omega + ir,A)|| < \infty \right\}.
\end{align*}
I have tried to prove this via rescaling the semigroup and then applying the Gearhart-Prüss theorem. But for this I need that the resolvents on the whole right-half plane are uniformly bounded and I get only boundedness on the imaginary axis. From the book "Vector-valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems" by Arendt and co. I also know that the growth bound $\omega_0(A)$ is equal to the pseudo spectral bound
\begin{align*}
s_0(A) = \inf \left\{ \omega > s(A) \colon \text{there exists $C_\omega$ such that $||R(\lambda,A)||\leq C_\omega$ whenever $\text{Re}\lambda > \omega$}\right\}
  \end{align*}
in the complex Hilbert space setting. So if I connect the two dots it must hold that if the resolvents are bounded uniformly on some imaginary axis $\omega + i r$ for $\omega > s(A)$ then they must already be uniformly bounded on the whole plane $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\colon \text{Re}\lambda \geq \omega\}$.
Any ideas on how to prove the exercise and if my conclusion about the extension of uniform boundedness to the plane is correct would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
